# make 4 digits if its less than 4 digit - Progress 4GL

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I want to convert a data to 4 digits value if it is less than 4 digits. for example, data1 is 145 then the program should convert it to 0145. Need to put 0 in front of the number to make it four. I tried below query but I feel this is not a correct way to do it. Note - I used variable cdata to store the data but no idea about while storing the data into table field should be stored as 4 digits value.

i.e if user enter value 1 then it should store 0001 in table field. If the user enter four and more than four digits value , Need to store as it is..no prefix to be added

```
define variable cdata as character no-undo.
cdata = "183".
if length(cdata) < 4 then cdata = "0" + cdata.
else if length(cdata) < 3 then cdata = "00" + cdata.
else if length(cdata) < 2 then cdata = "000" + cdata.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case you do need the leading zeroes in a character variable:

```
cdata = fill( '0', 4 - length( cdata ) ) + cdata.
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the STRING function - `STRING(145, "9999")` will do what you want.

The numeric data will be stored without the leading 0's but you shouldn't worry about that.